# How do I handle asynchronous calls when running newman (Postman) collections with node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman, postman-collection-runner, newman

I could do this with bash but I'm trying to learn node and would like to do it from there.  How do I get the newman run call to be synchronous.  I don't really understand the use of async/await (if that is what is required here). I have the following script that loops over a bunch of collection files (that each contain multiple requests) and calls newman run on each of them:

```
// node imports
const fs = require('fs');
const newman = require('newman');

// test variables
const testFolder = './api-tests/';

// read all files in the test folder
fs.readdirSync(testFolder).forEach(file => {
    console.log('Running file: ' + file);

    // run newman using the file
    newman.run({
        collection: require(testFolder + file),
        delayRequest: 500,
        iterationData: [
            {
                'host': 'localhost',
                'port': '8080'
            }
        ],
        reporters: ['cli', 'html']
    }, (err, summary) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(file + ' run complete');
    });
});
```

Newman executes each file immediately rather than waiting for the loop to go back around to the next file.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#eachSeries

Answer (score 1):

you can use deasync https://github.com/abbr/deasync

```
    var done = false;
    fs.readdirSync(testFolder).forEach(file => {
      newman.run({
      ...
      }).on('start', function (err, args) { // on start of run, log to console
            console.log('running a collection...');
      }).on('done', function (err, summary) {
            ...
            done = true;
      });
      require('deasync').loopWhile(function(){return !done;});
      done = false;
   }
```